# How to fix "Validate Connection" error could not find testMsDeployConnection when publishing Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webdeploy

How to fix "Validate Connection" error could not find testMsDeployConnection when publishing Azure Functions?

We can successfully use web deploy in Publish inside Visual Studio 2015 to deploy our Azure Functions

However if we try the "Validate Connection" option, we get a failure ...

```
Could not find file 'xxxxxxxxxx\.\obj\Debug\__testMsDeployConnection__'
```

But the folder is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known limitation of the Visual Studio tools for Azure Functions, as documented in the blog post: [Announcing Visual Studio Tools for Azure Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/).

As a workaround, you can use a web project to deploy, and you can then use a class library or script files. See [Publishing a .NET class library as a Function App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/).